# SharePoint 2013 branding

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a few questions regarding branding a SharePoint 2013 branding:

[image]

1. The above image is from the global navigation on the master page. I need to get rid of the arrow point down.
2. I have sub sites within sub sites and I need to navigate to the lowest child sub sites from my site collection. In the navigation settings, in global navigation I can add a Heading and then add links within that heading. How can I add Heading within a Heading, so that these lowest child sub sites can appear in my global navigation?
3. I want the search icon to be white instead of black in my search control.

Comment: You should avoid to ask multiple questions in the same post. The risk is that not one single user knows the answers to all of your questions and thereby does not answer at all. So please divide this post in to three separate posts

Comment: sincere apologies will be mindful of that

Answer (score 2):

Use firebug or IE tools to play around with the CSS. Here's something that can get you started:

```
/* Hide Nav menu arrow */
div.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox li.dynamic-children span.additional-background {
    background-image: none;
    padding-right: 0;
}

img.ms-srch-sb-searchImg {
    display: none;
}

div.ms-srch-sb > a.ms-srch-sb-searchLink {
    background: url("http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2672/pixel_ui/16/search.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

For 1.1 - I'm not sure if you can heading within heading.